# how to generate pandas dataframe basis list with condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have following list in python

```
 movie_list = [11, 21, 31, 41, 51, 62, 55]
```

and following movie dataframe

```
 userId      movieId
 1           11
 1           21
 1           31
 2           62
 2           55
```

Now what I want to do is generate similar dataframe, where `movieId` is not in dataframe, but there in movie_list

My desired dataframe would be

```
 userId      movieId
 1           41
 1           51
 1           62
 1           55
 2           11
 2           21
 2           31
 2           41
 2           51
```

How can I do it in `pandas`?

Comment: How exactly did you get from your list and first dataframe to your second dataframe?

Comment: you need to explain properly in order to get  the answer cause how can you assigning the userid from dataframe1 to the movie_list element's

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC, we can do the `agg` with `list` , then find the different between the original value in df with the `movie_list`

```
s=df.groupby('userId').movieId.agg(list).\
    map(lambda x : list(set(movie_list)-set(x))).explode().reset_index()
   userId movieId
0       1      41
1       1      51
2       1      62
3       1      55
4       2      41
5       2      11
6       2      51
7       2      21
8       2      31
```

Answer (score 3):

One approach would be to use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to create all combinations of `userId` & `movieId`, then [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
from itertools import product

movie_list = [11, 21, 31, 41, 51, 62, 55]
df_all = pd.DataFrame(product(df['userId'].unique(), movie_list), columns=df.columns)

df2 = pd.concat([df, df_all]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)

print(df2)
```

[out]

```
    userId  movieId
3        1       41
4        1       51
5        1       62
6        1       55
7        2       11
8        2       21
9        2       31
10       2       41
11       2       51
```

Answer (score 3):

```
prod = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.userId.unique().tolist(), movie_list]).tolist()
(
    pd.DataFrame(set(prod).difference([tuple(e) for e in df.values]), 
                 columns=['userId', 'movieId'])
    .sort_values(by=['userId', 'movieId'])
)


userId  movieId
7   1   41
6   1   51
2   1   55
8   1   62
5   2   11
4   2   21
3   2   31
1   2   41
0   2   51
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need:

```
 df = df.groupby("userId")["movieId"].apply(list).reset_index()
 df["movieId"] = df["movieId"].apply(lambda x: list(set(movie_list)-set(x)))

 df = df.explode("movieId")
 print(df)
```

Output:

```
    userId  movieId
0   1       41
0   1       51
0   1       62
0   1       55
1   2       41
1   2       11
1   2       51
1   2       21
1   2       31
```